# $query not executing in PHP but in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

So, this is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username' AND `password`='$password_hash'";
echo $query;
echo mysql_result(mysql_query($query), 0);
```

When I run this code in PHP, I take the query executed, and run it in phpMyAdmin, it shows the id 1. But it does not output anything, when the complete code is run, instead I get this error:

```
Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource
```

Comment: What do you get if you do `var_dump(mysql_query($query));` ?

Comment: I get this:     bool(false)

Comment: Note 1: [using the `mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) functions in new code is not recommended, as they are deprecated. Note 2: Your code is probably vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, depending on what you do with `$username` and `$password` beforehand. As per your problem, can you tell us what the username and password values are?

Comment: ... Then print out the error i.e. mysql_error (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) BTW - You should start using mysqli

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the php manual :

`mysql_query() will also fail and return FALSE if the user does not have permission to access the table(s) referenced by the query.`

Are you sure you are connected to the database and have to good rights ?

Comment: That was helpful, I looked back my whole connection file and there was one ( missing. But sadly it did not gave any errors on index, but did gave on connect file.

But now this is the new error:

    Warning: mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 8

Comment: Okay, I have finally solved it on my own. Thanks to Intrepidd for making me look my connection file. :D

Sorry for being a nub. :|

Comment: If this solved your question, please consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you setup you connection and query in a correctly

```
 $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
 if (!$link) {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 if (!mysql_select_db('database_name')) {
    die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM MyTable');
 if (!$result) {
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}
echo mysql_result($result, 0); // outputs first row

mysql_close($link);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users`
                  WHERE `username`='$username'
                  AND `password`='$password_hash'";
        echo $query;
        $sql_result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        echo mysql_result($sql_result, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and edit it accordingly requirement, and also check coallition of database to utf8_general_ci, and also keep tables in one kind as innodB...

```
  <?php
   $mysqli_hostname = "localhost";
   $mysqli_user = "root";
   $mysqli_password = "krunal";
   $mysqli_database = "krunal";
   $bd = mysqli_connect($mysqli_hostname, $mysqli_user,$mysqli_password,$mysqli_database);  
   if(mysqli_connect_errno()){die("database connection  failed");}
   ?>


   <?php 
   $sql= "SELECT * FROM `done`;";
   $result=mysqli_query($bd,$sql);
   if(!$result){
   die("database query failed". mysqli_connect_error()."(".mysqli_connect_errno().")");}?>



   <?php while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
   var_dump($row); }?>

   <?php mysqli_close($bd);?>
```